# Count all values, even if they are duplicated

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, duplicates

I need to count how many times a certain action happens on the last day of activity, even if this action happens with the same object several times. For example:
a person can take the same ski lift all day long, but I need to know how many times he actually took that ski lift in that day.

What I have so far is able to count how many times a person took DIFFERENT ski lifts on a certain date. But if I have a person that on the same date took 3 times the same ski lift, it will only count it as 1. Here's my query:

```
select SkipassNumber AS SkipassNumber, count(SkiLiftCode) AS TotSkiLiftLastDay
from actions_table
where ActionDate IN 
    (select  IIF(count(ActionDate) > 1, max(ActionDate), ActionDate)
        from actions_table
        group by ActionDate)
group by SkipassNumber, ActionDate
```

Sample Data:

```
SkipassNumber | SkiLiftCode   | ActionDate
--------------|---------------|------------  
001           | 111           | 12/31/2018
001           | 111           | 12/31/2018 
001           | 111           | 12/31/2018  
002           | 222           | 01/28/2019  
002           | 333           | 01/28/2019
```

I would expect to get from 001 a TotSkiLiftLastDay = 3

and from 002 a TotSkiLiftLastDay = 2

But what I get now is that 001 TotSkiLiftLastDay = 1 (this is **wrong**)

and from 002 a TotSkiLiftLastDay = 2 (this is **correct**)

Comment: Can you post some sample data with expected output from them?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. `group by SkipassNumber`.

Comment: post your expected output in tabular format....also add some more input data for better clarification. And what do you mean by `and from 002 as well.` complete this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'IT COULD WORK!'**

Thanks for all your help, in the end I made it work with a *over(partition by)*. Was hard, took me almost all morning, but I'm happy I finally made it work.

I'll leave the code for who's interested and for the next one who might need it.

```
select SkipassNumber AS SkipassNumber, count(SkiLiftCode) AS TotSkiLiftLastDay
from actions_table
where ActionDate IN 
    (select  max(ActionDate) OVER(PARTITION BY SkipassNumber))
        from actions_table
        group by ActionDate)
group by SkipassNumber, ActionDate
```

Peace!

Answer (score 2):

You may try this. Working fiddle [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/14b873/3).

```
select SkipassNumber AS SkipassNumber, count(*) AS TotSkiLiftLastDay
from actions_table
where ActionDate IN 
    (select  IIF(count(ActionDate) > 1, max(ActionDate), ActionDate)
        from actions_table)
group by SkipassNumber, ActionDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this :

```
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT SkipassNumber,SkiLiftCode,ActionDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SkipassNumber ORDER BY ActionDate DESC) TotSkiLiftLastDay
        FROM actions_table
    )

    SELECT
       *
    FROM cte
    where TotSkiLiftLastDay >1;
```

Comment: Seams like CTE is not supported

Comment: @eva what do you mean by not supported ?

Comment: just says that it is not an existing table. Don't know how it works TBH

Comment: it says only queries that start with a Select are valid

Comment: @eva what is the version of your DBMS ?

Answer (score 1):

I can see this answer is very similar to Amira's (hence my upvote of that answer) but hopefully a complete example with faked data will highlight how the concept of a CTE works.

Effectively you are building a derived table from a query which taking each skipassnumber, and ordering on the date descending. You can then join your original table on to it using the skipassnumber and the date. Then a simple aggregation will do exactly what you need it to do in terms of counting the number of events regardless of whether those events are unique or not.

```
declare @actions_table table (SkipassNumber int, SkiLiftCode int, ActionDate date);


insert @actions_table (SkipassNumber, SkiLiftCode, ActionDate)
values
(001           , 111           , '2018-12-31'),  
(001           , 111           , '2018-12-31'),
(001           , 111           , '2018-11-30'),  
(002           , 222           , '2019-01-28'),  
(002           , 333           , '2019-01-28');


with actiondates as (select row_number()over(partition by skipassnumber order by actiondate desc) rowno, skipassnumber, actiondate
from @actions_table)

select a.SkipassNumber, a.ActionDate, count(SkiLiftCode)
from @actions_table a inner join actiondates d on a.SkipassNumber=d.SkipassNumber
and a.ActionDate=d.ActionDate
where d.rowno=1 group by a.SkipassNumber, a.ActionDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a correlated subquery to identify the last date and then aggregate:

```
select SkipassNumber, count(*) AS TotSkiLiftLastDay
from actions_table at
where at.ActionDate = (select max(at2.ActionDate)
                       from actions_table at2
                       where at2.SkipassNumber = at.SkipassNumber
                      )
group by SkipassNumber;
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `actions_table(SkipassNumber, AcctionDate)`.

Window functions are also a solution.  For this case, I would use `max()`:

```
select SkipassNumber, count(*) AS TotSkiLiftLastDay
from (select at.*,
             max(ActionDate) over (partition by SkipassNumber) as max_ActionDate
      from actions_table at
     ) at
where ActionDate = max_ActionDate
group by SkipassNumber;
```

You can also do this without a subquery or CTE, but the performance will not be as good:

```
select top (1) with ties SkipassNumber, ActionDate, count(*)
from actions_table
group by SkipassNumber, ActionDate
order by row_number() over (partition by SkipassNumber order by ActionDate desc);
```